# Query fetches wrong value and NilClass in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi in the following code although the `where` query inside `create` method  i.e. variable `@count_of_fav_texts_present` fetches 1 record in the rails console, but in controller the value of `@count_of_fav_texts_present` is zero and going inside the first `if` clause.

Also in the internal `if` clause the query for `find_by` i.e variable `var_fav_text` is giving NilClass. Although when I check it in console the value is not Nil, and it has one record.

I am very new to Rails and I am not sure what mistake I am making. Please help.

```
class NewfavoriteTextsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_text
  before_action :set_favgroup
  before_action :authenticate_user!

def create
  @count_of_fav_texts_present = Favorite.where(favorited_id: @text_id, user_id: current_user.id).count

  if @count_of_fav_texts_present == 0
    if Favorite.create(favorited: @text, user: current_user)
      if Newfavorite.create(favorite_group_id: @fav_group, newfavorited: @text)
         var_fav_text = Favorite.find_by(favorited_id: @text_id, user_id: current_user.id)
         cnt_of_var = var_fav_text.counter
         var_fav_text.counter = cnt_of_var + 1
         var_fav_text.save
      else
         # do something
      end
    else
        # do something
    end
  else
    # for condition when var is greater than 0
    if Newfavorite.create(favorite_group_id: @fav_group, newfavorited: @text)
      var_fav_text = Favorite.find_by(favorited_id: @text_id, user_id: current_user.id)
      cnt_of_var = var_fav_text.counter
      var_fav_text.counter = cnt_of_var + 1
      var_fav_text.save
    else
      # do something
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  # do something
end

private

def set_text
  @text = Text.find(params[:text_id] || params[:id])
end

def set_favgroup
  @fav_group = params[:fav_group_id]
end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In both the query you have used **@text_id**. Try changing **@text_id** to **@text.id**

Comment: @dkp Thanks a lot for pointing out the error.. That was a silly mistake from my end.